# Непредвиденное появление: echo

Tags: cmd, bat

```
if exist D:\cmDos\resources\root\pass.txt (
    cls
    if %lang%==eng echo Welcome to CommandDisk Operating System!
    if %lang%==rus echo Добро пожаловать в CommandDisk Operating System!
    echo.
    if %lang%==eng echo This step is important to set up child's PC.
    if %lang%==rus echo Этот шаг является обязательным для настройки ПК ребенка.
    if %lang%==eng echo Please give your PC to your parent to type password.
    if %lang%==rus echo Пожалуйста, передайте ваш ПК вашему родителю для ввода пароля.
    if %lang%==eng echo It will lock access to cmDoStore as it contains inappropriate apps for your child.
    if %lang%==rus echo Он заблокирует доступ к cmDoStore из-за того, что он содержит неприемливые приложения для вашего ребенка.
    set /p pass=
    del D:\cmDos\resources\root\pass.txt
    goto welcome
)
```

Вроде бы, код правильный, но вечно вылазит такая ошибка на месте (echo.)
Не понимаю, что делать.

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Я не вижу ошибки. Я думаю, вы где-то допускаете ошибку при присваивании lang

Comment: Или при присваивании остальных переменных. Благодарю за ответ, RottenRat